# Isabelle/HOL: Prove one of de Morgan's laws using only rule, erule, and assumption

Tags: proof-verification, logic, foundations, natural-deduction

I wanted to give myself an intro challenge to Isabelle/HOL and prove De Morgan's law using only the rules of natural deduction (applying only rule *, erule * and assumption). However, I can't get it to work. I started out like this:

```
lemma "(¬P ∨ ¬Q) = (¬(P ∧ Q))"
  apply (rule iffI)
   apply (erule disjE)
    apply (rule notI)
    apply (erule notE)
    apply (erule conjE)
    apply assumption
   apply (rule notI)
   apply (erule notE)
   apply (erule conjE)
   apply assumption
```

This leaves me in the proof state

```
proof (prove)
goal (1 subgoal):
 1. ¬ (P ∧ Q) ⟹ ¬ P ∨ ¬ Q
```

From there on, I can't seem to make any progress. Is there anyone who knows how to derive the second part of the proof using the natural deduction rules coded down in Isabelle/HOL? No simp, blast, fast, metis, auto, or similar junk. This must be possible, but the Isabelle syntax is so obscure and poorly documented that I find it really hard to make progress.

Comment: The question is fine here and I don’t *call* for a migration, but I bet you would have better luck with getting an answer on [cs.se] and it’s just better fitting there. They have a tag for theorem-proving and even one for Isabelle there.

Comment: What rules did " rule *, erule * " include, since I didn't use Isabelle, it would be great if you can list them out

Comment: OK, I'll try to ask it on CS as well or migrate it somehow I guess (?)

Comment: I don't know the exact logical rules that Isabelle uses, but you need to use something equivalent to the Law of Excluded Middle to prove what you are trying to prove (`¬ (P ∧ Q) ⟹ ¬ P ∨ ¬ Q`).